# Clickable Link_to Table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, html-table, link-to

Is there any way to do a clickable td ?

```
<% @companies.each do |c| %>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><%= c.name %></td>...
```

Now I want to click on the name from the company and see another view (an overview from that company). 
Is there a way with link_to or something else?
By the way I want the name from the company shown at this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use link_to:

```
<td><%= link_to c.name, some_path %></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast help!